# how to get response from other PHP server to Rails server

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, nginx, amazon-ec2

Currently, I have one EC2 instance where I managed 2 apps. 1 for Rails and 1 for PHP (WP pages for blogs).
Both have different file directory structure.

Now in the Rails app, Nginx config file I have to redirect it to that PHP files when a particular address is called on my domain.

```
location ^~ /ab/ {

    root /home/wp/my-wp;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /p/index.php?$args;


    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
      expires 365d;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.*\.php)(.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Means on "www.domain.com", Rails app is running and when "www.domain.com/ab/something" is called then PHP ( WP ) server handled those requests.

Now I need to move this PHP ( WP ) to a new instance ( Currently on the same instance where Rails app is running ), So just wanted to know is there any way to get a response from that new instance to my rails app, whenever /ab/ is called. 
Simply, Don't want to change the domain to run the blogs. just wanted to works the same as previous but now with the new instance for PHP ( WP ).

Comment: You can simply proxy pass www.domain.com/ab/something request to your new PHP server from Nginx in rails App.

Comment: I added proxy_pass and it worked, however css and js are not loaded. page is served without css/js.


location ^~ /p/ {
    proxy_pass http://IP/wordpress;
 }
@a_k_v

Comment: The assets path is missing in your Nginx conf. try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657936/rails-nginx-not-serving-js-and-css